# How do I get the mouse position relative to the window, not the whole screen?

Tags: xna, c#, mouse

I am developing an XNA game. I run it in window mode.

I need to handle mouse events, but when I use the `Mouse` class from `Xna.Framework.Input.Mouse`, I get the the mouse position on the whole screen.

I use this code:

```
MouseState state = Mouse.getState();
Point position   = new Point(state.X,state.Y);

Rectangle hitbox = new Rectangle(180, 410, 14, 14);

if (area.Contains(mousePosition))
{
    //fire event
}
```

How do I detect the mouse position within the current game window?

Comment: Why do you need to get the position of the window? Most of the time you are only interested in the mouse position relative to the top-left of the game window, so I don't see why there's a problem.

Comment: By saying "position of the current Window"... i mean the game window.. sorry!

Comment: Can you post a picture demonstrating your issue. Also if you are using the debugger `Mouse.getState()` is updated even when the application is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

`Mouse` should default to reporting its position relative to the game window, but can be configured by assigning the appropriate window handle to `Mouse.WindowHandle`.

The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mouse.windowhandle.aspx).

Comment: i called this assignment in my `initialize` method, but it changed nothing .. `Mouse.WindowHandle = Window.Handle;` Where is my mistake?

Comment: "Is there a way to detect the mouse position of the current Game Window" is unclear, so I don't really know what you are experiencing. When the mouse is over the top-left corner of the window are you getting a mouse position other than (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, when my mouse is on the top left corner of the game window my mouse coordinates are (371,111).